# How to parse yyyy-Mm-ddThh:mm:ss format in dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I tried expression like below in mule dataweave but I am getting error.

```
pdate : "2017-06-22T12:45:55" as:datetime{format : "yyyy-Mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"} as :string{format: "MM/DD/yyyy"}
```

Can you please help on this if I missed anything to write.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dataweave, but shouldn't the format be `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy-Mm-dd`?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    pdate: "2017-06-22T12:45:55" as :localdatetime { format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" } as :string { format: "MM/dd/yyyy" }
}
```

changes compared to your version:

1. replace `Mm` with `MM` in first format string, thx @Dai
2. replace `hh` with `HH` in first format string
3. replace `DD` with 'dd' in second format string

[image]